# Shading Cells using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to Color a Particular Cell and `Shade it` using POI.
Normally to shade a Cell,one would select the Cell->rightClick->Format Cells->Fill(Tab)->Fill Effects, Select the Color and Select the Shading Style (for me here it will be GOLD and Shading style as HORIZONTAL 2nd Option).
The Problem i am facing is that i am not able to find a function that helps in Shading the Cell.Is this even possible using POI or maybe even jxl? Here is my code snippet:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:/poi-test.xls");
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("POI Worksheet");
HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow((short) 0);
HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.createCell((short) 0);
cellA1.setCellValue("Hello");
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GOLD.index); 
cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);\\ this part is probably redundant
cellA1.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following fill patterns for shading.

CellStyle.THIN_HORZ_BANDS, CellStyle.THICK_HORZ_BANDS,

Other possible fill patterns can be found from the below links:

[http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html#setFillPattern(short)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html#setFillPattern%28short%29)

http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/poi/filelColorInExcel.shtml